# Using one word for Pretty good

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, american-english

Is there a single word that can replace `pretty good`? Example - This book is pretty good.
Is there a way to shorten it?

Comment: "Pretty good" can mean a whole range of things depending on how you say it. We need to know more about what you're trying to connote.

Comment: Just *This book is **good*** if "pretty" is meaningless (the usual case). Otherwise, *This book is **okay*** or ***...excellent*** depending on whether you want to weaken or intensify the approval rating.

Comment: It's *fine*, it's *OK*, it's *decent*...any of them might apply, but as the other commenters have said, it's really all about context.

Comment: Yes, context and intonation. Those two allow for a range of answers from "acceptable" to "outstanding". If you use more specific words than "pretty good", we'll be able to give you a specific answer